# Offline inclusion of XMLSchema with xjc

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have an XSD file that reference and element `xs:schema`. When I run `xjc` connected to the internet it creates the appropriate JAXB objects. When I try and reference `XMLSchema.xsd` as a local file it fails.

How do I reference the local xsd file copy of `XMLSchema.xsd` so I can run `xjc` offline to create the JAXB classes?

Currently I call `xjc -d out schema0.xsd schema1.xsd`

Schema0.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="children">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="childname" />
                <xs:element ref="xs:schema" />
                <xs:any />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Schema1.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" 
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd" />
    <xs:element name="person">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: See: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/10/jaxb-xjc-imported-schemas-and-xml.html

Comment: Cheers @Blaise. Had a few fiddly issues with the XMLSchema.xsd. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the XMLSchema.xsd...

```
curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X GET http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd > XMLSchema-new.xsd
```

Remove the first section of the file from ...

```
<!DOCTYPE xs:schema PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XMLSCHEMA.....
.... To ....
<!ATTLIST xs:union id ID #IMPLIED>
]>
```

Download the xml.xsd file that XMLSchema.xsd references ....

```
curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X GET http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd > xml-new.xsd
```

Create a catalog file....

catalog.cat

```
SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" "XMLSchema-new.xsd"
PUBLIC "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" "XMLSchema-new.xsd"
PUBLIC "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" "xml.xsd"
```

Disconnect from the internet and run `xjc -catalog catalog.cat schema0.xsd schema1.xsd`

Thanks to Blaise for the detailed [article](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/10/jaxb-xjc-imported-schemas-and-xml.html). I failed to remove the `<!DOCTYPE` section of the XMLSchema.xsd and this was causing xjc to fail.